# AIC for robust generalized linear models (glm)

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, aic, robust

How can I calculate Akaike's 'An Information Criterion' with small sample size correction (AICc) for `glmrob` from `robustbase` in R? Family is `binomial(link = "logit")`. I can work with the original AIC if AICc can't be calculated. Everytime I use the functions `AIC(m)` or `MuMIn::AICc(m)` the output is always `numeric(0)`. The purpose is to assess if adding an extra term to the model increases model fit while penalizing adding the extra term.

Comment: I dont know how to get the AIC.

Comment: I cannot extract the likelihood value.

Comment: The AIC is defined only for models fitted by maximum likelihood. These aren't.